# Who to go to for diagnosis of random seizures?

Tags: common-cold, seizure

I don't have a history of seizures, nor does my family, but this started 4-5 years ago when I was asleep. They usually occur when I feel sick or have a cold or flu-like symptoms. An EEG test said everything was normal. It only happens at night when I'm asleep so maybe something is being triggered while in REM sleep?

How can I find a solution to this? Are there specialist doctors I can go to?

Comment: Hi there @Noah and welcome to health.SE! Sorry to hear about your condition, but this site isn't for diagnosis. I've reworded the question so that you might be able to get help, but otherwise, I think the way your question was previously worded might have been closed. If you feel that this doesn't help you, I would suggest rolling-back my edits and then rewording a little to ask something like, "What are some possible causes of  seizures when sick?", but again, this might be too broad. Still, I'd say you should give it a shot if that's what you want to ask. Again, welcome.

Answer (score 4):

I'll be answering this question in the way @DaveL edited the post.

The specialist you should go to is a neurologist. They are the ones who are most qualified when it comes to seizures.

In the mean time (because you'll probably have to wait before you can get an appointment), you can go to your GP and explain the problem. The way you're describing it, the EEG is probably normal because it would only changes when you're asleep and feverish, but maybe they'll like to redo it to see if there's an evolution, or test other hypotheses.

To these doctors, you'll have to describe the seizures precisely - when do they happen in the night? do you lose consciousness or not? is there abnormal body moves and if so, what kind? are you immediately able to think normally after they happen or are you slowed down for a while? did you bite your tongue? do you have witnesses of these seizures that could possibly notice something you didn't? did you take any medication that could have induced them or reduced them?

If you can, keep a journal of your seizures with these informations and bring it to your appointments. The more information, the better in these cases.

- [Guidelines](http://www.neurology.org/content/69/21/1996.full.html) of the American Academy of Neurology
- Exemple of [seizure journal](https://www.epilepsy.org.uk/sites/epilepsy/files/files/A4-online-seizure-diary.pdf)

Comment: I'd like to know which part of the post requires more references because I'm a bit confused there. I've added the guidelines of the AAN but would this answer needs more info on something else?

Comment: I think it would be best to speak with a moderator in the chat room or flag the question yourself with your question.